# Google Analytics Campaign or Medium Tracking with Privacy Browsers

Tags: privacy, google-analytics, tracking

If a user has a web browser or browser extension that blocks ads, disables cookies, stops tracking etc. Do these browser features stop Medium or Campaign information being passed to Google Analytics etc?

I have just been reading about Firefox Focus and its ad and tracking blocking but my knowledge of Campaign tracking with such browsers is limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at each of the things the user has turned off.

1. It blocks ads, this really won't stop Google Analytics (GA) from measuring your data. I believe the only data GA wont get is Demographics and Interests in the Audience section.
2. Disables cookies. This won't stop Google Analytics either! What it will do however, is that every time this aforementioned user visits the site - he would be treated as a new user (obviously after closing the previous browser instance).
3. The browser option of respect privacy is not really respected by Google Analytics, unless the implementation of the GA script includes that option. For this, the website owner has to include one more script in their website code -

   < script async src="//storage.googleapis.com/outfox/dnt_min.js">

And on top of this, while the GA tracker is being initialized, this code needs to be fired -

```
ga('require','dnt');
```

If you are a user and want to opt-out of tracking, you could always use the [GA Opt-out Browser Extension by Google](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gaoptout).

Comment: Thank you @prasad . Can I just throw something extra in there, with any of these setting and special privacy browser, do they strip URL parameters e.g 'www.MySite.com?utm_source=Post&utm_medium=Banener&utm_campaign=Post2017'

Comment: I have my AdBlock configured to block Google Analytics.   I just had to add a rule to do so.   AdBlock doesn't come configured that way usually, but it is very easy to make it work to block GA.

Comment: @TSQL_Newbie yes, the params are stored in _ga cookie.